# Line numbering per paragraph in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

How can I use line numbering in Word 2007, but for each paragraph? (By line numbering I mean the one from Page Layout/Setup, not regular list numbering)

So something like this:

**1** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

**2** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat

**3** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found a solution!

This effect can be faked using the regular outline numbering. Create a numbering outline format such that the numbering is without a dot or bracket:
1
2
3

Then right click on the paragraph and choose Adjust Line Indents
Set number position to be a negative number (-0.82 cm has exact same position as line number - may or may not be the same for you)
Set Text Indent to be 0 cm
Set Follow Number with to Tab character